# For two square matrices $A$ and $B$, does $AB=B$ imply $A=I$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If for two square matrices $A$ and $B$, one has $AB=B$ with neither being equal to the null matrix. Does it necessarily imply $A=I$ where $I$ is the identity matrix? What is the way to prove/disprove it for an arbitrary $n\times n$ matrix (with real or complex entries)?

Comment: Hint: consider $B = 0$.

Comment: Thanks. I should have added $B\neq 0$.

Comment: Hint: try finding a contradicting example with $n=2$, and $A^2= A$.

Comment: @GEdgar 's suggestion was the hint I had in mind too - oops, which he just deleted.

Comment: As per peter's hint, look for a $2$ by $2$ with determinant $0$ and trace $1$ so that it's characteristic equation is $\lambda^2-\lambda=0$. That is, $\lambda^2=\lambda$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $B$ be any non-invertible matrix. Then there is a non-zero vector $v$ such that $v^\top B = 0$. Now let $V$ be the matrix, each row of which is equal to $v$. Then let $A = I + V$. Then $$AB = (I + V)B = IB + VB = B + 0 = B.$$ On the other hand, if $B$ is invertible, then $$AB = B \implies A = ABB^{-1} = BB^{-1} = I.$$